# What's the quick way to make my change of firefox plugin take affect in windows?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpi

Now I have to restart whenever I modified a single line...

Is there a way to make it refresh without restarting the firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use plain directories in your extension instead of a JAR file, add `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>` to your `install.rdf` and add boolean `nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache`/`nglayout.debug.disable_xul_fastload` preferences and set them to `true`. You also start Firefox with `-purgecaches` command line flag (for Firefox 4 and newer). Then you will be able to edit extension files directly in the profile and have these changes picked up immediately. If you have an own dialog window then closing it and opening it again will be enough. For browser window overlays you will have to open a new browser window. JavaScript modules and XPCOM component will still need a browser restart however, these are loaded only once per browser session. But at least you won't have to reinstall the extension.

More information: [Setting up an extension development environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment)